# Tortoise connect to Server2012 visualSVN

Tags: windows-server-2012, tortoise-svn, visualsvn-server

I am moving my VisualSVN installation to a new server...
Windows Server 2012 with VisualSVN 3.3.1(non enterprise) and local workstation is Windows 7 with Tortoise 1.8.11

When I try to connect to the new instance with Tortoise, after I pass the SVN User authentication, I then get some kind of OS level login request.  This second request doesn't accept a valid os login/password or an SVN user/password.

The old (Server2008) instance works fine. (VisualSVN 2.5.23)

Answer (score 0):

Now working again.
I am assuming the following firewall rule somehow got flipped to disabled:
Secure Socket Tunneling Protocol (SSTP-In)
I enabled that rule since it allows port 443.
My original connect did automatically go to port 443. Subsequent connects failed until I enabled this rule.

Comment: False assumption - that wasn't it.  I had to re-add my SVN user's access to the repositories on the new server.  Dumb error.

Comment: In the end, on my new server, I had to install 2.5.23, so I could let the 3.3.1 install do its upgrade to my copied repositories, assigning the user authentication information under the newer (as of 2.7) scheme.

I am noting this here, in case anyone else makes a similar mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Move the existing installation first, then upgrade. Don't mix these tasks.

When moving VisualSVN Server from one computer to another, you should install the same version that is installed on the source machine first. I.e. in your case, you had to install VisualSVN Server 2.5.23 and configure it. Then you should move your repositories and upgrade only after that.

Before upgrading, read the guide ["Upgrading to VisualSVN Server 3.3"](https://www.visualsvn.com/support/topic/00085/).

FYI: We are currently working on a comprehensive instruction about moving VisualSVN Server from one machine to another.